# lodash orderby partial sort

Tags: javascript, angular, lodash

I have an array with elements shown below. I need to sort the array partially. Whereas all elements with `fix===1` should come first, with the order they appear in the dataset preserved. All others (`fix==0`) should then follow sorted by `jobDueDate`.

I have tried the following:

```js
_.orderBy(data, ['fix', 'jobDueDate'], ['desc', 'asc']);
```

Which will put entries with `fix==1` on top but will also apply sorting to them, which is not the requirement.

```js
[
  {
    "id": 6060,
    "jobNumber": 1878,
    "jobDueDate": "2018-02-07T00:00:00",
    "fix": 1
  },
  {
    "id": 5337,
    "jobNumber": 1836,
    "jobDueDate": "2018-02-05T00:00:00",
    "fix": 1
  },
  {
    "id": 5702,
    "jobNumber": 1863,
    "jobDueDate": "2018-02-06T00:00:00",
    "fix": 1
  },
  {
    "id": 32583,
    "jobNumber": 1611,
    "jobDueDate": "1753-01-01T00:00:00",
    "fix": 0
  },
  {
    "id": 33403,
    "jobNumber": 1932,
    "jobDueDate": "2008-01-28T00:00:00",
    "fix": 0
  },
  {
    "id": 29481,
    "jobNumber": 2741,
    "jobDueDate": "2018-02-03T00:00:00",
    "fix": 0
  },
  {
    "id": 278,
    "jobNumber": 1541,
    "jobDueDate": "2018-02-05T00:00:00",
    "fix": 0
  },
  {
    "id": 5331,
    "jobNumber": 1836,
    "jobDueDate": "2018-02-05T00:00:00",
    "fix": 0
  },
  {
    "id": 5708,
    "jobNumber": 1863,
    "jobDueDate": "2018-02-06T00:00:00",
    "fix": 0
  },
  {
    "id": 6066,
    "jobNumber": 1878,
    "jobDueDate": "2018-02-07T00:00:00",
    "fix": 0
  },
  {
    "id": 5193,
    "jobNumber": 1825,
    "jobDueDate": "2018-02-08T00:00:00",
    "fix": 0
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a custom sorting function which implements the required logic. If I got you right, this should do the trick for you:

```js
_.sortBy(input, (o) => o.fix == 1 ? 0 : o.jobDueDate);
```

Comment: That worked like an Awesome trick.Just one question how string based number/date need to be sorted out.

Comment: @AdnanAshraf : I am struggling a bit to understand your follow-up question. Can you please try to clarify what you are trying to do? Please note that the answer provided sorts dates alphabetically. Which is sufficient for the example data, but might not work in the real world. In that case you probably want to parse your timestamp to a datatype which implements correct ordering for dates.

Comment: What if I need to add another field with sorting e.g. based on o.fix == 0, sort by o.jobDueDate and o.paperSize.

Whereas o.paperSize are digits based numbers but in string format. Due to string format "1280 " number will be on top as compare to "250" in ascending order

Comment: It's probably best if you do open a new question for that.